# Kotlin - Nested functions vs private function with 1 callsite

Tags: kotlin

Whenever I have a function which has gotten large enough to warrant decomposing into smaller functions, I always go for creating the smaller functions as nested functions of the larger functions scope like so:

```
class Foo {
    fun bar() : Int {
        fun a() : Int {
            // Do a load of stuff
            return 1
        }
        fun b() : Int {
            // Do a load of stuff
            return 1
        }

        return a() + b()
    }
}
```

I do this as it provides encapsulation of these functions which as of yet only have a single callsite; that of the enclosing scope.

However I am frequently asked at work to refactor these functions out to private functions of the enclosing class like so:

```
class Foo {
    fun bar() : Int {
        return a() + b()
    }

    private fun a() : Int {
        // Do a load of stuff
        return 1
    }

    private fun b() : Int {
        // Do a load of stuff
        return 1
    }
}
```

My argument against this is that these functions only have 1 callsite, and by hoisting them to class level private functions I am muddying the class with methods that are only called in one place.

An additional minor argument can also be made that if I make them private functions of the class, someone can come in later and start inserting methods between those private functions and the function that calls them, such that there could be 100's of lines of code between the callsite and the functions themselves, causing mental gymnastics to be required to understand the calling function (as you now need to scroll the calling function off the screen to see the private functions).

I always comply and move them to private functions of the class after my argument doesn't pursuade the reviewer(s).

Is my argument valid or are there legitimate reasons (performance, code readability) that make my argument invalid?

Comment: See this article: https://medium.com/tompee/idiomatic-kotlin-local-functions-4421f86ac864. Local functions in Kotlin are apparently turned into anonymous classes implementing `FunctionN`, which can be a little more overhead. I don't think you can inline local functions either

Comment: So there is a performance argument for not doing it the way I'd prefer, that's fair. Although that argument has yet to be put forward to me at work.

Comment: I never capture variables in my nested functions, not for performance reasons but for ease of refactoring later if I do indeed need to hoist those functions out to private functions if they are going to have 2 or more callsites. I just parameterize the nested function if it needs stuff from the enclosing scope and pass those in when I call them.

Comment: Whenever Kotlin starts using `invokedynamic` to create new Function instances instead of anonymous classes, the performance gap will be even smaller though

Comment: If you're not calling these local functions more than once, you may be able to use the `run` function instead to organize code within your outer function. `val resultA = run { /* Do a bunch of stuff */}` IMO, it's clearer than and just as maintainable as nested functions that are only called once.

Comment: And a slightly facetious alternative (but it might actually work) if you need to call them multiple times is to make them lambdas. Might get overlooked by your code reviewers. :)

Comment: lol, nice idea tenfour xD

Comment: You could possibly make an annotation processor for this, so you can write functions as if they're local, but they get moved outside while compiling

Comment: @ThomasCook maybe you coworkes are mainly from java background and not used to the idea of functions inside functions. I agree that your approach is better.

Comment: Just to offer an alternative point-of-view; as a Java dev transitioning to Kotlin, the benefit of limiting the scope doesn't outweigh the cost in terms of readability to me. Nesting functions within functions add to my mental stack when reading the code. Limiting the scope of the inner function seems nice, but not critical given it's not part of the classes' API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find very confusing to transform nested functions into private functions within the class that contains the function, since the only purpose is just to improve the readability of the main function. The private clause only protects against inadvertent use outside the class, but it hinders the readability of the class's source code.

In terms of efficiency, there are no problems, quite the opposite, but it's irrelevevant. In compiler time the search for valid functions within the class is more streamlined, since the nested functions are not even part of the data dictionary.

In terms of efficiency, there is a small overhead when allowing the nested function to see part of the context of the parent function, which is in an earlier section of the code. Since use is only as a means of achieving better readability, I see no problem with that.

As a private function, the compiler can access the function anywhere in the class, which I think is an encapsulation flaw, since that is not the purpose of a local and
nested function.